# How to allow an inactive user to log in and use the /user/ endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am using rest-auth and I want to allow the users reactivate their accounts by their own.

I managed to allow the inactive user to log in by using `AllowAllUsersModelBackend` in `settings.py`

```
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend",
]
```

And then I disallowed rest-auth to check respond with an error message by deleting these lines from the `LoginSerializer`:

```
    if not user.is_active:
        msg = _('User account is disabled.')
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
```

I also customized the `UserDetailSerializer` to allow deactivation and activation by adding `is_active` field of the user model.

Now I can log in using a deactivated user and it sends me a JWT back, but when I try to use the `/user/` endpoint it respond with that error:

```
{
    "detail": "User account is disabled."
}
```

I want to allow them to use this endpoint to reactivate their account but without allowing them to use any other custom endpoint that requires authentication.

Comment: The whole point of deactivating users is to disallow logins. Are you sure you need users to log in in order to re-activate their account? Wouldn't a dedicated endpoint where they enter their username/password work?

Comment: Maybe instead of using Django account deactivation, you'll enter your own eg flag. "Is_suspended"? The user will be able to log in, but you will check if the account is not suspended before performing any action.